# Remove error of my code Please

Tags: java, android

Here is my code where m trying to extracting aal data from server but error is coming at "setImageView()" method. Can any one please help me as soon as possible.  my code is about displaying info and images from server.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlantDetails extends Activity {

    String whichPlantId;
    String whichPlantName;
    String whichFamily;
    String whichSystemOfMedicineUsed;
    String whichHabit;
    String whichMedUses;
    String whichCultStatus;
    String whichExplanation;
    String whichimageurl;
    ImageView tvTemp8;
    Activity convertView;
    //finding all textView and ImageView 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plant_details);
        TextView tvTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpplant_id);
        TextView tvTemp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpfullplantname);
        TextView tvTemp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpfamily);
        TextView tvTemp3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpdep_ref);
        TextView tvTemp4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dphabit);
        TextView tvTemp5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpmeduses);
        TextView tvTemp6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpcult_status);
        TextView tvTemp7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpexplanation);

        tvTemp8 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dpimageurl);
        Intent iGetDetails = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iGetDetails.getExtras();
        whichPlantId = b.getString("plant_id");
        whichPlantName = b.getString("fullplantname");
        whichFamily = b.getString("plantfamily");
        String whichDptRef = b.getString("dptRef");
        whichSystemOfMedicineUsed = "SysMed";
        if(whichDptRef.contains("A"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Ayurveda";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("S"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Siddha";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("U"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Unani";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("H"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Homeopathy";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("F"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Folk";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("T"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Sowa-Rigpa";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("M"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Modern";
        }
        if(whichDptRef.contains("C"))
        {
            whichSystemOfMedicineUsed += ", Chinese";
        }
        whichSystemOfMedicineUsed = whichSystemOfMedicineUsed.replace("SysMed, ", "");
        whichHabit = b.getString("habit");
        whichMedUses = b.getString("meduses");
        whichExplanation = b.getString("explanation");
        whichCultStatus = b.getString("cultStatus");
        whichimageurl = b.getString("imageurl");
        //seting Textview and imageview
        tvTemp.setText("Plant Id is " + whichPlantId + " Image url is " + whichimageurl);
        tvTemp1.setText("Plant Name: " + whichPlantName);
        tvTemp2.setText("Family:" + whichFamily);
        tvTemp3.setText("System of Medicines: " + whichSystemOfMedicineUsed );
        tvTemp4.setText("Habit:" + whichHabit );
        tvTemp5.setText("Medicinal Uses:" +  whichMedUses);
        tvTemp6.setText("Cultivated Status:" + whichCultStatus);
        tvTemp7.setText("Explanation:" + whichExplanation);
        tvTemp8.setImageResource(whichimageurl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_plant_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: SO is not about debugging your code. Please read the site's guidelines.

Comment: yes i know,if u have any idea then tell about my error...

Comment: You go wrong here`tvTemp8 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dpimageurl);` __convertView=null__

Comment: M D i have created image adapter to set data and i passed it by intent but after that all data is coming but image is not set error is at setImageView() method,so which method i used to set imageurl to image view

Comment: where is the image adapter being used, anyway that would be a different question, if you go past the current error

Comment: so can i declare convertView=null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 tvTemp8 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dpimageurl);
```

`convertView` is not needed.  And if you want to search in view hierarchy of current activity,
`convertView` is not initialised.

Inside `onCreate()`,
`convertView=this;`
or
`convertView=PlantDetails.this;`.

Comment: thank you user what is ur name?

Comment: @sahil - none of your business :-)

Comment: doesn't matter, good till user2450263 gets you a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            Log.e("src",src);
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

tvTemp8.setImageResource(whichimageurl);change this line to this line

tvTemp8.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(whichimageurl));
```